# Using Intel Edison via Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, intel, iot, intel-edison

Can someone help me to use my Intel Edison via Arduino IDE?

I have the latest version of Arduino IDE, installed with the installer provided on Intel's website. I receive those error messages (they are in portuguese):

Arduino: 1.6.6 (Windows 8.1), Placa:"Intel® Edison"

> Aviso: platform.txt do núcleo '[0}' contém algo depreciado
>   (recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}"
>   {compiler.ar.flags} "{build.path}/{archive_file}" "{object_file}"),
>   automaticamente convertido para
>   recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}"
>   {compiler.ar.flags} "{archive_file_path}" "{object_file}". Considere
>   atualizar este núcleo. Aviso: platform.txt do núcleo '[0}' contém algo
>   depreciado (recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}"
>   {compiler.ar.flags} "{build.path}/{archive_file}" "{object_file}"),
>   automaticamente convertido para
>   recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}"
>   {compiler.ar.flags} "{archive_file_path}" "{object_file}". Considere
>   atualizar este núcleo. Placa Intel:i586:izmir_fg não define uma
>   preferência 'build.board'. Autoconfigurada para: I586_IZMIR_FG Placa
>   Intel:i586:izmir_fd não define uma preferência 'build.board'.
>   Autoconfigurada para: I586_IZMIR_FD Placa Intel:i686:izmir_ec não
>   define uma preferência 'build.board'. Autoconfigurada para:
>   I686_IZMIR_EC exec:
>   "C:\Users\bruna_zamith\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\tools\core2-32-poky-linux\1.6.2+1.0/pokysdk/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux/i586-poky-linux-g++":
>   file does not exist Erro compilando.

And there are other messages like, for example:

> Invalid library found C:\Users\bruna_zamith\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.2+1.0\libraries\Wire: C:\Users\bruna_zamith\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.2+1.0\libraries\Wire

What can I do to compile sketchs to my Edison?
I have configured the port and choosen "Intel Edison" on Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

The fix was suggested in 
https://communities.intel.com/thread/93908?start=0&tstart=0

> <<< Content from orignal post slightly altered >>>
>   ZohaibArshad, it should work fine in 1.6.6.  Came across that same error today, what you need to do is rename the file ....../arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/i686/1.6.2+1.0/libraries/Wire/libraries.properties to library.properties

Here is the original thread that led me to that https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=362521.0